# Powershell Contiguous Date summary

Tags: arrays, powershell, date, datetime, sccm

From this object (and others like it):

```
    $Times = @(
    "12:00 AM",
    "1:00 AM",
    "2:00 AM",
    "3:00 AM",
    "4:00 AM",
    "5:00 AM",
    "6:00 AM",
    "7:00 AM",
    "8:00 AM",
    "9:00 AM",
    "10:00 AM",
    "11:00 AM",
    "12:00 PM",
    "1:00 PM",
    "2:00 PM",
    "3:00 PM",
    "4:00 PM",
    "5:00 PM",
    "6:00 PM",
    "7:00 PM",
    "8:00 PM",
    "9:00 PM",
    "10:00 PM",
    "11:00 PM"
)

$Example = @()
$times | % {$time = $_; $Example += [pscustomobject]@{Day = 'Sunday'; Time = $time;RatelimitingSchedule = '100'}}

$Example[5].RatelimitingSchedule = '50'
6..20 | % {$Example[$_].RatelimitingSchedule = '10'}
$Example[21].RatelimitingSchedule = '50'

$Example
```

This produces output like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Opbg.png)

My question is, how can i massage that into this summarized form (in the order shown):

- between 5am and 6am, 50% Rate limiting
- between 6am and 9pm, 10% Rate limiting
- between 9pm and 10pm, 50% Rate limiting
- between 10pm and 5am, 100% Rate limiting

Any assistance most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this in the future... https://www.reddit.com/user/bis/ kindly created this for me:

```
 &{ $Example; 0 } | # append a dummy to the end of the data, so the last record gets processed
  ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $StartTime = $EndTime = $null
    $CurrentRate = -1
  } -Process {
    if($_.RateLimitingSchedule -eq $CurrentRate) {
      $EndTime = $_.Time
    } else {
      if($null -ne $StartTime) {
        [pscustomobject]@{Start = $StartTime; End = $EnDTime; Rate = 
    $CurrentRate}
      }
      $StartTime = $EndTime = $_.Time
      $CurrentRate = $_.RateLimitingSchedule
    }
  } |
  ForEach-Object {
    "between $($_.Start) and $($_.End), $($_.Rate)% Rate limiting"
  }
```

As part of this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/wpuxm2/24hour_contiguous_schedule_summary/

Comment: Hello! It would be helpful if you would add the output (or a sample of the output) of this script so that other users can decide if it meets their needs.